# Jordan-Holder theorem for Abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

The Jordan Holder theorem for abelian categories states that if you have an object with a "Jordan-Holder Filtration" which is one where the subsequent quotients $X_i/X_{i-1}$ are simple objects, then one can extend any filtration of this object into a Jordan-Holder Filtration. Moreover any two Jordan Holder filtrations have the same set up to multiplicities of simples appearing as quotients as above up to isomorphism.

I can't figure out how to prove this as the proof of the same theorem in the group case doesn't pull through. Does anybody know a reference for this or how to go about proving this?

Comment: You could appeal to the Freyd embedding theorem. There's probably a better way though.

Comment: Related MO question : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324108/categorical-unification-of-jordan-holder-theorems

Comment: @hunter I'm not sure it's that simple. The comments under [this other MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343130/applications-of-jordan-holder-theorem-in-an-abelian-category) are related.

Comment: It's not true in general. Indeed, there are abelian categories that have no simple objects at all, so no object has what you call a Jordan-Hölder filtration. The normal statement of the Jordan-Hölder theorem requires a finite length object..

Comment: This is true, sorry, i'll change the question

Answer (score 3):

Note, that if $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian category and $a\in\text{Obj}(\mathcal{A})$, then $\text{Sub}_{\mathcal{A}}(a)$ is a bounded modular lattice. Now the desired statements are special cases of the Schreier refinement theorem and the Jordan-Hölder theorem for bounded modular lattices (see, for example: Bo Stenström, "Rings of quotients", p.66).

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{Sub}_{\mathcal{A}}(a)$ need not be a set in general; you probably have to add it as an hypothesis.

Comment: @ArnaudD. This condition seems irrelevant here. For example, in NBG nothing prevents you from considering bounded modular lattice structures on proper classes and applying the same theorems to them.